# I want to create a program in C to check for @ and . if typed in by user

Tags: c

Checking email address if user typed in `@` and `.` symbols. How can I fix the code?

```
void emailaddress(){

    char emailadd[50];

    int emailaddL, i;
    printf("Please enter your email address\n");
    scanf("%s", emailadd);
    emailaddL=strlen(emailadd);
    for(i=0; i<=emailaddL; i++){
        if(emailadd[i]!='@'){
            printf("The entered email address is incorrect. Please re-enter your email address and it must contain the '@' specifier\n");
            emailadd=(int*)calloc(emailadd, sizeof(char));
            scanf("%s", emailadd);
        }
        if(emailadd[i]!='.'){
            printf("The entered email address is incorrect. Please re-enter your email address and it must contain the '.' specifier\n");
            emailadd=(int*)calloc(emailadd, sizeof(char));
            scanf("%s", emailadd);
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: With `if(emailadd[i]!='@')` it looks like you expect *every* character to be `'@'` so I advise you to reconsider the logic. If one is found, increment a counter and check it is `1` after the loop. Similarly with `'.'` but there may be more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem your code is facing is not about C but about the logical structure of your function. If your `emailadd` contains any character different from `@` and/or different from `.` you ask for a new email address.
That's not what you want.

Let's structure your problem. Here is what you want to do:

1. Get user input
2. Check if the input contains an `@`
3. If not, ask for new input
4. Check if the input contains a `.`
5. If not, aks for new input

You don't want to do this once, but as long the user input is correct. To be even more precise you want to get a `.` after the `@` (otherwise an email address like `stack.overflow@so` would be valid.

Consider this approach which implements exactly the behaviour defined above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char emailadd[50];
    size_t emailaddL;   /* Use size_t instead of int */

    /* Get the email address for the first time */
    printf("Please enter your email address\n");
    scanf("%s", emailadd);
    emailaddL=strlen(emailadd);

    /* Loop while the address has a wrong format */
    while(1){
        /* Create flags: 0 character missing, 1 character found */
        int at_flag=0;
        int dot_flag=0;
        emailaddL=strlen(emailadd);

        /* Loop through the char array. You have to loop from 0 to the array lenght -1*/
        for(int i=0; i<emailaddL; i++){    /* You can declare variables in for loops */

            /* If an @ has been found, set the flag */
            if(emailadd[i] == '@'){
                at_flag=1;
            }
            /* If a . has been found and @ has been found earlier, set the flag */
            if(at_flag && emailadd[i] == '.'){
                dot_flag=1;
            }
            /* If both flags have been set, you can stop searching */
            if(at_flag && dot_flag){
                break;
            }
        }

        /* If no @ has been found, ask for it */
        if(!at_flag){
            printf("The entered email address is incorrect. Please re-enter your email address and it must contain the '@' specifier\n");
            scanf("%s", emailadd);
        /* If an @ has been found, but no ., ask for it */
        } else if(!dot_flag){
            printf("The entered email address is incorrect. Please re-enter your email address and it must contain the '.' specifier, after the '@' specifier\n");
            scanf("%s", emailadd);
        /* Otherwise leave the loop */
        } else{
            printf("Everything is fine!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Let's try some scenarios:

```
$ Please enter your email address
$ stack.overflow 
$ The entered email address is incorrect. Please re-enter your email address and it must contain the '@' specifier
$ stack.overflow@so
$ The entered email address is incorrect. Please re-enter your email address and it must contain the '.' specifier, after the '@' specifier
$ stack.overflow@so.com
$ Everything is fine!
```

Comment: If my answer could solve your problem you can accept it as correct. Learn more about accepting an answer by reading [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you are looking for a more personal and inofficial way of sharing thoughts about programming you should check out [Stackoverflow Chats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're looping too far into the string, your end condition in the for-loop should be i

Secondly, you're reporting an error at the first character you find that is not an @ which means you're basically saying that all characters need to be an @. And if it actually is an @ if will also need to be a '.' or the code will fail on the next if.

And when you fail you shouldn't reallocate memory for emailadd, it is already allocated. scanf will add a trailing zero to the input so you don't even have to zero the array.

Also when your validation fails, it will continue to loop over the array at the index it was at before your scanf.

So you probably want to do something like:

```
bool foundAt,foundPeriod;
do {
    foundAt=false;
    foundPeriod=false;
    scanf("%s",emailadd);
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(emailadd); i++) {
        if (emailadd[i]=='@') foundAt=true;
        if (emailadd[i]=='.') foundPeriod=true;
    }
} while(!foundAt&&foundPeriod)
```

But of course, this is not a good validation for an email address.